# How do I change/edit the size/shape/color of "Account" and "Cart" Button in an rwd theme?

Tags: rwd-theme

I have an issue of not being able to figure out how to change the size/shape of the "Account" and "Cart" button in the rwd theme. I have search through the css to no avail as it seems to not directly labeled these two buttons? Anyone figure this out? I like to make these buttons less gaudy as they are to large to suite my theme. I also like to figure how to make them little more rounded. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

For account you can edit `a.skip-link` which will be around `line no 3264` in `style.css` see this pic and for `cart` the `css` will be around `line no-3268` in `style.css`,and if you want to add any div classes you can do that for `account` section goto `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/page/html` and open `header.phtml` and find this code this code is responsible for `account` section

```
<a href="#header-account" class="skip-link skip-account">
     <span class="icon"></span>
     <span class="label"><?php echo $this->__('Account'); ?></span>
</a>
```

and this code

```
<div id="header-account" class="skip-content">
       <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topLinks') ?>
</div>
```

responsible for links which will be displayed when `account is clicked`

`cart` links fetched from

`app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart` `minicart.phtml` you can add any `<div>` classes in this page and this links are fetched using this code in `header.phtml` file

```
<div class="header-minicart">
     <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('minicart_head'); ?>
</div>
```

Hope this helps and if you need more assistance feel free to ask.

Comment: I would strongly recommend that you don't edit the css files directly, but rather edit the scss files and then follow the instructions here to setup Sass compilation: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ee114-ce19-rwd-dev-guide

Comment: @ErikHansen I know that I forgot to add that point actually I just mentioned that file anyway thanks for your comment :)

Answer (score 1):

If you look in the [Working with Sprites](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ee114-ce19-rwd-dev-guide#customize-theme-images-sprites) section of the Magento RWD theme documentation, you will see links to where you can download the source PSD files that contain the sprites that include the Account and Cart icons. If you open the PSD with Photoshop, you will be able to customize those icons. Here is a direct link to the PSD: http://www.magentocommerce.com/images/uploads/RWD_icon_sprite.psd

Comment: This only helps with icons but not the button size.